# Nginx - 100% usage CPU

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

Nginx used 100% CPU all cores.
Nginx works fine for a 1-2 hours, next CPU JUMP to 100% usage and I have to reboot server. I Updated nginx to latest version 1.10 and still this same problem. 
Could someone tell me what wrong is with my config?
[image]

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

[image]

Comment: What sort of application are you running on top of nginx? Can you identify in the logs if there are particular requests that might be causing the issue?

Comment: it's video stream. Big video file displaying on videoplayer online.

Comment: Can you check network usage? Is it possible that it's a valid user generated peak? Also, why are you are the files already compressed using an appropriate video codec? If so why is gzip enabled?

Comment: all videos are converted by ffmepg to mp4. Gzip was enabled like default conf. I should disable gzip?
Usage network is around 60%

Comment: Yes, you should disable gzip compression at least for the mime type of you video files as it does not reduce the size of the files and incurs in unnecessary cpu usage. What is the network usage in bytes per second?

Comment: please check 1 post. (new img with network)

Comment: It seems that you are using all your bandwidth (assuming a 1gbps link) so usage is high. Can you disable gzip and check if cpu usage goes down at similar network usage?

Comment: Now  usage is around 1% CPU. But now is not a max users online.

Comment: Good. Please let me know if this solves the issue when you get a chance to measure with more users online. If it does then I'll post and answer so we can move this from the comments. Thanks!

Comment: I will let you known. Thanks

Comment: still this same usage CPU 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132709/discussion-between-cjungel-and-jensej).

Answer (score 0):

Please decrease keepalive_timeout by average API response time or 30 seconds.
Please check how many socket are open there.